# Check if the hostname is fully qualified (FQDN)

Tags: bash, fqdn

```
#!/bin/bash

for h in "bert" "ernie" "www.google.com"
do
    host $h 2>&1 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$h is a FQDN"
    else
        echo "$h is not a FQDN"
    fi
done
```

Like to insert the output of 'hostname -f' instead of 'bert' or www.google.com
If the hostname is FQDN the script should continue, if not an error message should occur. PS. It is NOT important if the TLD exist or not. eg. hostname.domain is a FQDN or hostname.domain.tld is a FQDN. If the TLD is valid on the internet is not important to me. [output of hostname -f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GacXF.png)

Comment: If the TLD doesn't exist, how do you know if it's fully qualified?

Comment: hostname = NOT FQDN and hostname.domain = FQDN

Comment: BTW, `test $?` is an antipattern - just use the result of `host` directly in `if`; for example, `if host "$h" >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...; fi`.

Comment: If you just want the output of `hostname -f`, why are you asking this question?

Comment: I want the use the output of hostname -f to determin whether I want the continue or exit te script. hostname only is exit and fqdn mean continue.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to ensure a hostname is fully-qualified is to specify the final `.` (that is usually omitted): `example.com.`.

However, from comments to the question, it appears that you want a simple string comparison - if a `.` appears anywhere, assume the name is valid, otherwise error.  The simplest way is to compare the name against a copy with first `.` removed - if the two are identical, then there was no `.` to remove:

```
if [ "$h" != "${h/.}" ]
then echo "$h is acceptable" >&2
else echo "$h is not acceptable" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for h in "bert" "ernie" "www.google.com"
do
    if [[ ${h//[^.]} != "" ]]
    then
        echo "$h contains ."
    else
        echo "$h doesn't contain ."
    fi
done
```

if it supports regexp

```
if [[ $h =~ \. ]]; then
```

Comment: instead of bert or ernie I would like the output of "hostname -f", can you do that?

Comment: `hostname -f "$h"` ?